# Passing a variable from Eloquent to Controller

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.5

Is it possible to pass a variable from Eloquent to Controller?
I have here my code for Eloquent where i get the result of my filtered query and i wanna use that same variable to my Controller so that i can use it for my Exporting to excel.
Here's my code for my eloquent model:

```
$result = $query
        ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
            ->paginate($perPage);

        if ($search) {
            $result->appends(['search' => $search]);
        }
        if ($emp_status) {
            $result->appends(['emp_status' => $emp_status]);
        }  
        if ($company) {
            $result->appends(['company' => $company]);
        }
        if ($age) {
            $result->appends(['age' => $age]);
        }
        if ($tenure) {
            $result->appends(['tenure' => $tenure]);
        }
        if ($benefit) {
            $result->appends(['benefit' => $benefit]);
        } 
        if ($level) {
            $result->appends(['level' => $level]);
        } 
        if ($gender) {
            $result->appends(['gender' => $gender]);
        } 
        if ($civil_status) {
            $result->appends(['civil_status' => $civil_status]);
        } 
        if ($birthmonth) {
            $result->appends(['birthmonth' => $birthmonth]);
        } 

        return $result;
```

How can I get "$result" and use it in UsersController?

Comment: I guess that you should make instance of model in controller and then call proper function that return your $result.

Comment: What is `$result`?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need to use something like a [query scope](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#local-scopes) in your model

So something like this in your model:

```
public function scopeWhatever($query)
{
    return $query->
        ...
        your conditions
        ...
}
```

Then in your controller use:

```
YourModel::whatever()->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you add the function to the controller, and call it there. But if for some reason, you need it in the Eloquent class, I can suggest one of these two:

- make a new instance of your model without saving it, and call the method with it.

`(new Model())->myFunction();`

this will work for any instance of the model.

`myInstanceOfTheModel->myFunction();`

- the better solution(in my opinion), is using a trait. write a trait with that function and add it to both your model and controller.

`

```
trait QueryFunction(){
  theQuery(){
    //your function comes here
  }
}

class SomeController extends Controller{
  use QueryFunction;
}

class YourModel extends Elloquent{
  use QueryFunction;
}
```

`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
Model::query()->where($yourConditions)->get();
```